# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 607, 11), found shape=(None, 11) with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to make a model to predict loan eligibility and keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/loan-eligibility-predictor/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    model.fit(x,y, epochs=1000)
  File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/gm/qccyh6h11p58bn4j_cnrqksc0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_filetfmlokfq.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/Users/XXX/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 614, 11), found shape=(None, 11)
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas 
import tensorflow 


dataset = pandas.read_csv('/Users/XXX/loan-eligibility-predictor/loan-train.csv')
x = dataset.drop(columns=['Loan_Status'])
y = dataset['Loan_Status']


model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(x.shape)))

#input layers
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')) 
#hidden layers
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')) 
#output layer
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y, epochs=1000)
```

and here is my dataset:
https://github.com/bruhbot-dev/loan-eligibility-predictor/blob/main/loan-train.csv

I have tried searching previously asked questions but not had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

The input size of your model is not specified correctly.
You have:
`model.add(tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(x.shape)))`

But it should be

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(x[0].shape)))`

The input of the model is the dimension of ONE sample, not all samples.